React js make background blur when input is focused
I want to create an input field like in the picture, if the input field becomes focused then I want to change the background to blur
image example
Do I have to use a certain library? I'm currently using Material UI

If you are using Material UI, the Backdrop component is something you could try.
You will be able to blur the background, showing only your menu component in the front

Thank you for your help, I made changes to the z-index to be bigger than the z-index of the Backdrop component. By default the z-index of the Backdrop is 1201, so I changed it to be bigger than that
